# Writing echo to script

Tags: bash, shell

In a bash script, I need to create another script file, So I have the following

```
cat >/etc/script2.sh <<EOL
#!/bin/bash

mysql -e "SHOW TABLES FROM $DATABASE_NAME" > /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt

echo "$(tail -n +2 /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt)" > /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt
EOL
```

However, the `echo` at line 5 is executed and the output is added to `script2.sh`

How can I have `script2` to look like

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -e "SHOW TABLES FROM $DATABASE_NAME" > /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt

echo "$(tail -n +2 /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt)" > /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt
```

Without been `echo` executed?

UPDATE

With my current code when `/var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt` does not exist I get `tail: cannot open '/var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt' for reading: No such file or directory`

When the file exists I get something like

```
mysql -e "SHOW TABLES FROM reaction_production" > /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt

echo "table1
table2
table3" > /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt
```

Script2 must be evaluated when executed in the future, not when written now.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what the script2.sh looks like after executing above code.

Comment: You need to scape the $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scape the `$` on the process substitution so that it is treated as a `string` in the current script and thus, evaluated when executing `script2.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

  cat > /etc/script2.sh << EOF
#!/bin/bash

mysql -e "SHOW TABLES FROM $DATABASE_NAME" > /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt

echo "\$(tail -n +2 /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt)" > /var/lib/mysql-files/tables.txt
EOF
```